# Magento 2 : Admin Data Grid is not displaying correctly

Tags: admin, grid, magento2.1.5

I have fresh install magento 2.1.5. Every thing is working well except admin data grid. I also run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy, but issue still exists.
[image]

When I use inspect element i found that th tag around span tag is missing.
[image]

How I solve this issue, This issue is with all ui component grid.

Comment: have you fixed issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same exact issue.  It seems to have something to do with the server configurations not applying the JS correctly.  Knockout JS was attempting load the templates for the admin data grids, but the  tags weren't being rendered, now allowing the columns to be counted when it reaches the toolbar.js file.

**Solution**

Go to your Magento Root and add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear

var/generation

Var/cache

Var/di

Execute all this commands

`Bin/magento cache:clean`

`Bin/magento cache:flush`

`Bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`Bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`Bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**Make sure to set proper permissions.**

Comment: issue still exists...

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too.

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```